# Convert from uri escaped string to original characters string (C#)

Tags: c#, url, escaping, urldecode

I have a string that represents a uri escaped string.

I want to convert it to original characters string.

For example:

```
6B%2FdHJaYVYZ9%2BkbVbNwB%2FmxPXwJhzmfIC8aUWOg%2F2mFCWzyrXaRHFsYLZSVedck3UW3FppuUG0jn2f4JMVUx9Q%3D%3D
```

is needed to be converted to: (Desired output)

```
6B/dHJaYVYZ9+kbVbNwB/mxPXwJhzmfIC8aUWOg/2mFCWzyrXaRHFsYLZSVedck3UW3FppuUG0jn2f4JMVUx9Q==
```

The convertion is written here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

%2F is need to be converted to '/'

%2B is need to be converted to '+'

%3D is need to be converted to '='

and etc.

Comment: It's not `base64` encoded... your desired output is ... why dont you just use `Uri.Unescape(input)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string is not base64 encoded it's just uri escaped string. To unescape it you can use built in method from `Uri` object which is called `UnescapeDataString` :

```
string uriString = "6B%2FdHJaYVYZ9%2BkbVbNwB%2FmxPXwJhzmfIC8aUWOg%2F2mFCWzyrXaRHFsYLZSVedck3UW3FppuUG0jn2f4JMVUx9Q%3D%3D"
string unescaped = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uriString);
Assert.AreEqual("6B/dHJaYVYZ9+kbVbNwB/mxPXwJhzmfIC8aUWOg/2mFCWzyrXaRHFsYLZSVedck3UW3FppuUG0jn2f4JMVUx9Q==", unescaped);
```

[Online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vJMimd)